# Is it a good idea to hold reference to both recyclerview and its adapter separately in a fragment/activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

What I would like to know is will it cause a big difference in performance/efficiency if I held class variables for both my recyclerview as well as the adapter, just because I want to reduce the amount of code I have to type every time I want to call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no downside in having a reference to the adapter as well. In fact it's even more performant (but insignificantly) because you will save some extra method calls (like `recyclerView.getAdapter()`). Also, the code is more readable and easier to maintain this way ;)
Consider having a look on this [presentation from Jake Wharton](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/eliminating-code-overhead-square-hq-2015) to learn more optimization tips.

Comment: do you maybe have a link to a youtube video where he speaks over the presentation?

Comment: There is a link in the description.

Comment: So trading memory for lesser cpu churn is better?

Comment: Using too much memory can be harmful as well, because the GC will kick in more often and the user will notice dropped frames. But in your case, a reference only has 4 or 8 bytes in size, which is really insignificant compared to the size your adapter already has in memory, for instance.